# Adding geom_text or annoation to stat_density_ridges plot

Tags: r, plot, geom-text

I have a stat_density_ridges plot and I'd like to add some text (in this case a z-score) to each individual ridge in the plot. If I could get the text in the top right of the plot even better.

As an example, this code 'as written' will plot a ridge plot but it tries to put all the z-scores on ridge 'A' and runs out of room so only adds the first then produces warnings.

I have discovered that if I make the 'value' col of data_df character class (change the # from line 4 to line 3) I get the correct z-score on the correct ridge, but of course I don't get any ridges because the data type is wrong.

Any help getting both ridges and annotation on the same plot would be much appreciated.

```
data_df <- data.frame(group=c(rep("A",26),rep("B",26),rep("C",26),rep("D",26)),
                     sample=rep(letters,4),
                     value=rnorm(26*4, mean=0, sd=1))
                     #value=as.character(rnorm(26*4, mean=0, sd=1)))

z_scores_df <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","D"),
                             z_score=runif(n=4, max=1, min=0))

plot = ggplot(data_df, aes(x=value, y=group)) +

  stat_density_ridges(aes(fill=after_stat(quantile)), 
             geom = "density_ridges_gradient", scale=1,
             calc_ecdf = TRUE) +

  geom_point(data=data_df[data_df$sample=='w',],
               color="green", size=2) +

  geom_text(data=z_scores_df,
            aes(label = format(z_score,digits = 3), x= Inf, y=1), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 1.1),
            inherit.aes = F) + 
  NULL

plot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add `vjust=` and `hjust=` in the `aes()` from `geom_text()` to adjust the position of `z` scores (you can play with the values to adjust the positions). Also the `y` value in the `aes()` should be group to add `z-score` values by group:

```
plot = ggplot(data_df, aes(x=value, y=group)) +
  
  stat_density_ridges(aes(fill=after_stat(quantile)), 
                      geom = "density_ridges_gradient", scale=1,
                      calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  
  geom_point(data=data_df[data_df$sample=='w',],
             color="green", size=2) +
  
  geom_text(data=z_scores_df,
            aes(label = format(z_score,digits = 2), x= Inf, y=group,vjust = -8,hjust=1), 
            position = position_stack(),
            inherit.aes = T) + 
  
NULL
plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use use the `annotate()` function in `ggplot2` to add annotations to each ridge.

For one ridge 1 this would be:

`annotate("text", x=Inf, y=1, label=z_scores_df$z_score[1], hjust=1.1, vjust=1.1, size=3)`

In order to avoid repeating yourself we coul use `map2` from purrr package to combine all 4 annotations in a list `z_score_annotations`:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggridges)
library(purrr)

z_score_annotations <- map2(z_scores_df$z_score, seq_along(unique(data_df$group)),
                            function(z_score, group_num) {
                              geom_text(data = z_scores_df[z_scores_df$group == unique(data_df$group)[group_num],],
                                        aes(label = format(z_score, digits = 3), x = Inf, y = group_num),
                                        hjust = 1.1, vjust = 1.1, size = 3, inherit.aes = FALSE)
                            })
plot = ggplot(data_df, aes(x=value, y=group)) +
  
  stat_density_ridges(aes(fill=after_stat(quantile)), 
                      geom = "density_ridges_gradient", scale=1,
                      calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  
  geom_point(data=data_df[data_df$sample=='w',],
             color="green", size=2) +
  
  z_score_annotations +
  
  NULL

plot
```

[image]